# use of string in place of URL (in anti XSS)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, xss, antixsslibrary

I need to find a way to implement encoding.

Since HTML Encoding is not working, hence I am using:

```
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;
```

and then:

```
AntiXssEncoder.UrlEncode(**Iam passing string here**)
```

This measure resolves my issue(Positive results in HP Fortify), however I am concerned since instead of URL I am using string. Would this result into any impediments?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;
```

and then:

```
string Comment= AntiXssEncoder.XmlAttributeEncode(passing string here);
```

or to accept HTML tags that put text in bold or italics;
check content manually.

```
    public static bool DangerousContent (string text)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        if (
            text.Contains("<body>") ||
            text.Contains("<embed>") ||
            text.Contains("<frame>") ||
            text.Contains("<script>") ||
            text.Contains("<frameset>") ||
            text.Contains("<html>") ||
            text.Contains("<iframe>") ||
            text.Contains("<style>") ||
            text.Contains("<layer>") ||
            text.Contains("<link>") ||
            text.Contains("<ilayer>") ||
            text.Contains("<meta>") ||
            text.Contains("<meta>") ||
            text.Contains("<applet>")
           )//can add more
        {
            Status = true; 
        }
        return Status;
    }
```